# Change color of the Cmd+Tab app switcher on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, application-switcher

Is it possible to change the color (specifically, darken) the cmd+tab application switcher on yosemite?

It's hard to see, especially against a white background:

[image: light yosemite cmd-tab switcher]

Comment: are you using dark mode?

Comment: No… I didn't even know that was a thing! But that looks like exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can darken the the background of menu bars in Yosemite using "Dark mode".  To enable this go to System Preferences-->General, and check the box next to "Use dark menu bar and Dock".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download AltTab for Mac from [Github](https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos) or their [website](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) and choose appearance as Windows 11. You will solve 2 issues:

1. There is a WHITE square border on the windows selected IN CMD TAB APP SWICTHER
2. you can switch between windows of the same apps, like MS Excel, just as in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Windows

[image]

More information is available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3B8154vF1Q)

Comment: I just discovered AltTab last week, and it is amazingly powerful. Great description on how to use it to solve a problem.